# First contact resolution

Tags: sql, db2, teradata

I have a data set of phone calls in DB2. My stakeholders have asked me to provide a report on customers who have not called back within 24 hours of their last phone call.

If you're not too busy could you give some ideas on what could achieve this in DB2. I can also import the data to SAS, MySQL or Teradata.
The data looks like this:

```
 Date/Time                   Call_ID_PK         Customer_ID_FK
 
 2020-06-24 10:57:34         1154171YUY         11111111
 2020-06-24 11:02:21         2675765HGH         71766443
 2020-06-24 11:12:45         3687677GFR         67884833
 2020-06-24 11:17:03         4876876HGD         36733633
 2020-06-24 11:19:22         4967867GFG         55672446
 2020-06-25 09:10:57         7755555DSW         11111111
 2020-06-25 09:12:43         7958755HUE         76876258
```

Have a great day,

Cameron

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the idea and concept of StackOverflow. Please take the [tour] to understand that this is a community of programmers to help programmers with specific programming problems they encounter while trying to implement things. You in contrast to that are asking here for a solution instead of demonstrating what you tried, explaining the problem you encountered and reporting on the research and debugging you did.

Comment: Thanks but I'm really stuck with this one and can't get my head around the logic of where to begin. My first thoughts were to import it all into a temp table and then select all customers who aren't in that table compared to a refreshed table 24 hours later. But I can't see that being efficient ongoing. I don't want anyone to write the script for me. I just want to bounce ideas. I've been writing SQL for 7 years and this has stumped me.

Comment: The table includes the users who have made calls. We'll need a table with the full user base to determine the missing ones. Please add that table.

Comment: Look into the `NOT IN` and `OUTER JOIN` language elements.

Comment: include your db2 platform and version

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in Teradata:

```sql
SELECT customer_id_fk, MAX(call_timestamp) AS LastCall
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY customer_id_fk
HAVING MAX(call_timestamp) <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

This will return a list of customers whose most recent call is more than one day old.

To get a more complete list, you'd want to reference a "customer" table to account for customers who haven't placed any calls at all.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply :)  It helps a lot. The other table will be tricky. There’s over 17 million customers.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped.  The query itself isn't tricky -- you can do something like this: `SELECT ... FROM <user_table> u LEFT JOIN <call_table> c ON u.userid = c.customer_id_fk GROUP BY ...`.  This will get all users and their call information, if any.  But with 17M rows, it could take some time if not properly indexed.